# Is it possible to create a external Wep application with Facebook Notification with auto sync?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, real-time-updates

I have a web application. Is it possible to do the auto sync the facebook notification with my web application using facebook Graph-API. If yes please let me know the solution

Comment: _Is it possible..._ Did you try anything?

Comment: yes, I tried to use the Real-time Update concepts, which is comes with graph API in Facebook. But I don't know how to write the callback method in my server and also I don't know the exact flow of it.